# Python eliminate Tuples after zipping list of list of lists

Tags: python, list, csv

If have something like this read from multiple csv files:

```
[[['A', 'B', 'C'], 
  ['1', '2', '3'], 
  ['2', '4', '6'], 
  ['3', '6', '9'], 
  ['4', '8', '12'], 
  ['5', '10', '15'], 
  ['6', '12', '18'], 
  ['7', '14', '21'], 
  ['8', '16', '24'], 
  ['9', '18', '27']], 
 [['D', 'E', 'F'], 
  ['4', '5', '6'], 
  ['8', '10', '12'], 
  ['12', '15', '18'], 
  ['16', '20', '24'], 
  ['20', '25', '30'], 
  ['24', '30', '36'], 
  ['28', '35', '42'], 
  ['32', '40', '48'], 
  ['36', '45', '54']], 
 [['G', 'H ', 'I'], 
  ['7', '8', '9'], 
  ['14', '16', '18'], 
  ['21', '24', '27'], 
  ['28', '32', '36'], 
  ['35', '40', '45'], 
  ['42', '48', '54'], 
  ['49', '56', '63'], 
  ['56', '64', '72'], 
  ['63', '72', '81']]]
```

Now i want to "paste" the columns together. So i had the idea to do this with zip:

```
map(zip, *l)
```

This gets me this, which is pretty close:

```
[[('A', 'D', 'G'), ('B', 'E', 'H '), ('C', 'F', 'I')], 
 [('1', '4', '7'), ('2', '5', '8'), ('3', '6', '9')], 
 [('2', '8', '14'), ('4', '10', '16'), ('6', '12', '18')], 
 [('3', '12', '21'), ('6', '15', '24'), ('9', '18', '27')], 
 [('4', '16', '28'), ('8', '20', '32'), ('12', '24', '36')], 
 [('5', '20', '35'), ('10', '25', '40'), ('15', '30', '45')], 
 [('6', '24', '42'), ('12', '30', '48'), ('18', '36', '54')], 
 [('7', '28', '49'), ('14', '35', '56'), ('21', '42', '63')], 
 [('8', '32', '56'), ('16', '40', '64'), ('24', '48', '72')], 
 [('9', '36', '63'), ('18', '45', '72'), ('27', '54', '81')]]
```

So is there a short and clean way to get all the numbers/letters in one inner list together and rid of the tuples ?

**EDIT:**
Just for the info: now knowing more about functional programming, here is what i was looking for in haskell (pretty sure numpy supports these functions as well)

```
import Data.List
zip' = map concat . transpose
```

Comment: Would you prefer a column order of A, B, C, D, etc., or is A, D, G, B, etc. the way you want it?

Comment: A, B, C ..... just as if i would have pasted them together in csv

Comment: Are you looking for `['ADG', 'BEH', CFI']`, and so on?

Comment: no for [[A..I], [1,4,7...9]....]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're willing to use numpy, the following would work

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.asarray(l)
>>> mat, row, col = data.shape
>>> data = data.swapaxes(0, 1)
>>> data
array([[['A', 'B', 'C'],
        ['D', 'E', 'F'],
        ['G', 'H ', 'I']],

       [['1', '2', '3'],
        ['4', '5', '6'],
        ['7', '8', '9']],

       [['2', '4', '6'],
        ['8', '10', '12'],
        ['14', '16', '18']],
...
>>> data.resize((row, mat*col))
>>> data
array([['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H ', 'I'],
       ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'],
       ['2', '4', '6', '8', '10', '12', '14', '16', '18'],
...
```

Not sure if that's what you wanted, but I find it cleaner and easier to follow than `map`s within list comprehensions.

**EDIT**: FYI, the condensed implementation would be merely the following, assuming `data` is already a numpy array -- note that you can also read the csv with `np.genfromtxt()`, that you way don't need to copy the list.

```
>>> mat, row, col = data.shape
>>> data = data.swapaxes(0, 1).reshape(row, mat*col)
```

The more obscure alternative is to do:

```
>>> data = np.asarray([d.flatten() for d in data.swapaxes(0, 1)])
```

**Much Improved Solution**

Hadn't thought of it for some reason, but you can do it in one unambiguous function call:

```
>>> np.hstack(data)
```

Comment: like the solution for being pretty short... on the other side i probablly wount know what "zippedList = np.asarray([d.flatten() for d in np.asarray(parsedList).swapaxes(0, 1)])" did in 2 Days from now...  But thank you for pointing out numpy. Seems to be an interesting library.

Comment: Great :) Just edited some more. You can load the data with `np.genfromtxt()`. Reduces the need for the `csv` module, which you may or may not be using.

Comment: You mean where the delimiter is `\t`?

Comment: Yeah looked it up just know. But i just realiced, that this would prob just make it more complicated/slower since i do a lot of "parsing" while reading in on specific criteria.

Comment: Numpy also allows for some pretty cool conditional indexing. Up to you though!

Comment: Ok. Than i have to try that for certain. At the moment i have to meet a deadline... thx.

Comment: Please see updated answer. It can't get shorter and cleaner.

Answer (score 3):

```
import itertools

L = myHugeListFromMultipleCsvFiles
output = [list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(sub)) for sub in zip(*L)]
```

Or, if you want to go the more functional way:

```
output = list(map(list, itertools.chain.from_iterable(zip(*L))))
```

Comment: Your second solution doesn't give the same result.  Did you want something like `map(list, map(itertools.chain.from_iterable, zip(*x)))` instead?  (Perhaps with an extra outer `list` call so that it still works in Python 3.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using list comprehension after the `map(zip , *l)` , to get the elements from inner sublists and then merge them to a single list (flatten list of lists to list).

Example -

```
>>> l1 = [[z for y in x for z in y] for x in map(zip, *l)]
>>> l1
[['A', 'D', 'G', 'B', 'E', 'H ', 'C', 'F', 'I'], ['1', '4', '7', '2', '5', '8', '3', '6', '9'], ['2', '8', '14', '4', '10', '16', '6', '12', '18'], ['3', '12', '21', '6', '15', '24', '9', '18', '27'], ['4', '16', '28', '8', '20', '32', '12', '24', '36'], ['5', '20', '35', '10', '25', '40', '15', '30', '45'], ['6', '24', '42', '12', '30', '48', '18', '36', '54'], ['7', '28', '49', '14', '35', '56',
 '21', '42', '63'], ['8', '32', '56', '16', '40', '64', '24', '48', '72'], ['9', '36', '63', '18', '45', '72', '27', '54', '81']]
```

Comment: yeah... i thought of that as well. I am just not sure if there is maybe a reordering or another function that does this shorter